# Remove columns from a dataframe meeting a treshold of non-zero values

Tags: r

I want to split a dataframe by the number of non-zero values, say I want to remove all columns with more than *n* zeros. I know how to remove all zero-sum columns:

```
df[, colSums(df) != 0]
```

But how to do this for any treshold for zero elements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to create a logical matrix and then do the `colSums`

```
 n <- 3
 df[colSums(df==0) <= n]
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(22)
 df <- as.data.frame(matrix( sample(0:4, 5*20, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```

Comment: @CathG Sorry, I didn't get your point.  Can you elaborate with an example

Comment: nevermind, I think I misread the question, I thought OP was doing `df[, colSums(df) != 0]` to remove columns with only zeros and so that couldn't work if, for example, the column was `c(0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0)` so I was just saying your way was better...

Comment: @CathG After your comment, I re-read the question.  But his description and the code is different.  For example `I want to remove all columns with more than n zeros` and the code is what the OP knows about doing a different thing.

Comment: exactly, I re-read also after your comment and saw I misunderstood the purpose of the displayed code the first time ;-)